# Why does moving my mouse really quickly make recaptcha pass quicker?

Tags: web-application, captcha

I've noticed that if I ever get [recaptchas](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) on websites if I move my mouse back and forward really quickly then it passes very quickly.

Any idea why/if this is a possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking about the No Captcha ReCaptcha here. This tick based ReCaptcha works based on javascript and a CSS styling element unlike the form input based conventional CAPTCHA. Google is relying on the fact that most bots doesn't have javascript support and will not be able to fire the ajax request which is usually fired when the user clicks on the check box. It may also be relying on the javascript to capture mouse actions. More mouse actions create more entropy which a bot ideally cannot mimic. This could be the reason why your random mouse movements made an easy pass through the reCAPTCHA.

***This is an educated guess.***

Answer (score 1):

I think this is only a perception and not actually the case. I would do a video of 10 recaptures, 5 with mouse movement and 5 without, and count the frames. If that video confirms your idea then repeat with 100 more for real significant results.

The reason I believe this is due to my assumption of what is happening when you are waiting for confirmation of being human is that the recapture provider is checking your meta data for reasons to suspect you to not be human. This can be seen as when you use TOR you end up having to authenticate your humanity with puzzles, this is due to your IP address being marked as possible non human. Mouse movement would not aid in this as mouse movement data can be made and sent programmatically.